# (Shiny error when using bookMark feature) ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am new to using Shiny and creating Shiny Apps. I am currently running the latest versions of R and the latest version of the Shiny App and the latest version of RStudio on Windows.

I'm experiencing severe problems using the "bookMark" feature that R claims works. There was even a more than half hour long video from the 2017 either RStudio or Shiny conference with an R engineer gushing over the wonderful addition of the bookMark feature and the bookMark feature doesn't work.

I am able to click the button and copy the link and I'm bookMarking to the server. But when I paste the link into the browser I'm always getting the error following error and it DOES NOT RENDER the PAGE in the SAME STATE that I "Bookmarked" it. It just does not work:

ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

I'm using Google Chrome as my browser:

Here is the code that it appears to be producing the error on:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
  hist(data)
```

I have NO idea why I'm getting an error on something that's just supposed to work out of the box as is. The software is supposed to save the state of the slider and put it back to its state that was supposed to be saved when I clicked bookMark. It doesn't work. I'm not too optimistic that anyone will answer my question with an actual solution. I did extensive searches before I submitted this question and people have been having this problem for months if not years.

ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

Hopefully someone out there knows a solution to this problem.

Thanks.

B.B.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/L_Al1prDhdM)

*"If you're running Shiny 0.8.0 or later, try running this before calling runApp()":*

```
options(shiny.error=recover)
```

*"Or, if you're using the latest version of RStudio, this is even better:"*

```
options(shiny.error=browser)
```